# Oracle Function Does Not Guarantee It Does Not Update Database

Tags: sql-server, function, oracle12c

I am running into an issue when calling a SQL Server stored procedure from an Oracle function.  We have created a gateway between the two databases and an Oracle function that calls the SQL Server stored procedure.  When we call the function using an @call, the function works as desired.  However, when we call the function from within a SELECT statement, we receive an:

> ORA-06571 Function X does not guarantee not to update database.

We have tried putting the function within a package and using RESTRICT_REFERENCES(X, WNDS), but still run into this issue.  We are restricted in that the Oracle function needs to be called within a SELECT statement.  Examples below:

**SQL Server Stored Procedure Signature**

```
PROCEDURE sql_server_proc(@param1 NVARCHAR(255), @param2 NVARCHAR(255), @param3 NVARCHAR(255), @rtn_val1 INT OUT, @rtn_val2 FLOAT OUT);
```

**Oracle Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(param1 VARCHAR2, param2 VARCHAR2, param3 VARCHAR2)

RETURN INTEGER AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE

        rtn_val1 INTEGER;
        rtn_val2 NUMBER;
        rtn_val3 NUMBER;
        result NUMBER(8, 2);

    BEGIN
        result := sql_server_proc@sql_server(param1, param2, param3, rtn_val1, rtn_val2, rnt_val3);
        COMMIT;
        RETURN rtn_val1;
    END;

END;
```

**Oracle SELECT SQL (Throws ORA-06571 Error)**

```
SELECT test_func(‘XYZ’, ‘ABC’, ‘123DFG’) FROM DUAL;
```

**Oracle @Call SQL (Works)**

```
 @call ${returnValue||(null)||BigDecimal||noshow ds=0 dt=NUMERIC dir=out}$ = test_func('XYZ', 'ABC', '123DFG');
 @echo returnValue = ${returnValue||(null)||BigDecimal||noshow ds=0 dt=NUMERIC dir=out}$;
```

Any ideas on how to get the SELECT statement to work?

Comment: Could this be something? https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/calling-stored-procedure-as400-from-oracle-1699 ie, you should declare the stored procedure in the ora file

Comment: Should the `COMMIT` be there?

Comment: Yes, what purpose does the `commit` serve in your Oracle function, since you aren't performing any changes to the Oracle database?